# What is the relation between kinetic energy and momentum?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, kinematics, momentum

If kinetic energy is doubled, what happens to momentum? Is it also doubled?

I've tried working through the formulas for each but keep getting lost.

$$KE=\frac{mv^2}{2}$$

$$p=mv$$

so if $v=\frac{p}{m}$ then $KE= \frac{m}{2} \cdot (\frac{p}{m})^2$  so $KE=\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{p^2}{m}$

then  p= (2KEm)^1/2 ...so if KE is doubled what happens to p?

Comment: Write down the equations in your question. See if you can manipulate kinetic energy so it is expressed in terms of $p$ and $m$ (get rid of $v$).

Comment: I'm not sure how to get rid of v here..

Comment: Try substituting $v = \frac{p}{m}$? Update the question with your effort (use the "edit" link).

Comment: ... and remember speed is squared in kinetic energy.

Comment: I'm still confused...

Comment: Can you solve for $p$?

Comment: Solve your last formula for $p$.  That is, algebraically rearrange your last formula so that it is $p=$*something*.  That might help you see what's up.

Comment: Ok then p= (2KEm)^1/2    so then if KE is doubled, what happens to p?

Comment: When you have $p_1=\sqrt{2m\cdot E}$ and $p_2=a\sqrt{2m\cdot 2E}$, then $p_2/p_1=\sqrt{2}$. If you have difficulty with that manipulation, you need to seriously beef up your math skills if you want to stick with physics. That's not meant in a derogatory way - just honest advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your last equation you get $2KE=\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{p_{final}^2}{m}=2 \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{p_{initial}^2}{m}$

so you'll get: $p_{final}=\sqrt2 p_{initial}$

Answer (score 1):

The relation between Kinetic Energy and momentum is derived in the following way. I hope this answers your question.

[image]